# Share internet from laptop to a wireless router

Tags: routing

My laptop is currently connected to xfinitywifi which is great but what I want to do essentially share my internet connection from laptop to wireless router then have the wireless router send out signal to my other devices (smartphones Xbox streaming devices etc)

I already know how to turn my laptop into a hotspot which is great but the xfinitywifi only work in one area of my house, I need it in my bedroom but my laptop signal from xfinity is terrible weak, so what I’m trying to do is place my wireless router in my room, setup xfinitywifi on my laptop in the living room and use a 25ft Ethernet cable to share my internet to my wireless router then the router would then send out WiFi signal in my room at max speed...at least that’s how I assume it would be

However I’m currently stuck at the first step which is sharing my laptop internet connection with my wireless router. Can anyone help me with this? Tried bridging and sharing, none seems to work. :(

Comment: Windows 10 has the ability to create a virtual hotspot.  “However I’m currently stuck at the first step which is sharing my laptop internet connection with my wireless router.“ just connect the router to the virtual hotspot.

Comment: i need the internet connection in my bedroom, and my laptop can “only” connect to xfinity from the living room, so if I were to connect through wireless the connection would drop significantly,so I’m using an Ethernet cord  to connect my laptop to my wireless router which in all practical sense is done, but the wireless router isn’t receiving the data for some reason, tried sharing and bridging@ramhound

Comment: What OS is the laptop running?

Comment: My solution doesn’t involve xfinitywifi

Comment: Possibly related: [Share wireless Internet connection over the same wireless adapter?](https://superuser.com/q/808788/354511), [Two routers in one house, want one to stand alone from the other](https://superuser.com/q/974939/354511), and [Wi-Fi extender, extending a cellular hotspot](https://superuser.com/q/778218/354511).

Answer (score 1):

You can share your wifi Internet connection over LAN.   You only need to connect your router to the LAN port of your laptop. Use ICS (INTERNET CONNECTION SHARING) in Windows. Connect the LAN cable from your laptop to the Internet port of the router. Configure DHCP addressing on router so  that you get an automatic IP for the router. Keep all the setting in router as it is.
Hope you will be able to do it.